# Qual DB usar para o PHP7?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Boa tarde pessoal beleza ?

Gostaria de sugestões  de qual DB usar para o PHP7, ouvi falar que o mysql com o php7 da muito erro e ele é obsoleto,

Alguma sugestão de artigos ?

OBS: vou usar para um projeto para WEb Que talvez eu fassa uma API para o desktop e App(mobile)

Obrigado.

Comment: Obsoleta é apenas a API que contém as funções `mysql_` e não o banco de dados.

Comment: Como atualmente existe o PHP PDO, você pode utilizar qualquer banco de dados conectado a ele, porém se fizerm em PHP ou PHP OO deverá se conectar com MySQL. Mas, PHP se conecta com qualquer banco, useo banco de dados na qual tem maior facilidade

Comment: Valeu :D Abração